# Adding a .a file to a project via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I am currently working on a project that is using CocoaPods. This is my first experience using them and would love some help with an issue we are having.

We have multiple apps that use the same data models. Instead of duplicating code, we created a separate project that is added to each sub project as a pod file. In this project we also have a lot of our 3rd party libraries(Facebook SDK, GoogleAnalytics, etc) as they are used across our multiple applications. 2 libraries we use are Flurry 5.4.0 and Appsflyer. Unfortunately these guys are .a files as opposed to the other pod files which return .h files.

[image]

The base project we have will clean and compile no problemo. But when we try to add this project, through pods, to any of the sub project, it results in this compile error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerTracker", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libPods.a(SHAnalyticsUtility.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libPods.a(SHAnalyticsUtility.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried all different methods of updating the Podfile(https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2018) and PodSpec(https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/1483) file but nothing has worked so far. Any and all suggestions welcome :)
**PODSPEC**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|


  s.name     = 'company-framework-ios'
  s.version  = '1.13.16'
  s.platform = :ios
  s.license  = 'MIT'
  s.summary  = 'Framework for all the iOS apps'

  s.source_files = 'CompanyFramework/CompanyFramework/*.{h,m}','CompanyFramework/CompanyFramework/**/*.{h,m}'

  s.frameworks = 'QuartzCore', 'CoreLocation'
  s.dependency 'Masonry'
  s.dependency 'Mixpanel'
  s.dependency 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'
  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '2.4.1'
  s.dependency 'NSDate+Calendar'
  s.dependency 'RXPromise'
  s.dependency 'SAMCategories'
  s.dependency 'FlurrySDK'
  s.dependency 'AppsFlyer-SDK'
  s.dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.18.2'

  s.ios.deployment_target = "7.1"

  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.vendored_library = 'Pods/FlurrySDK/Flurry/libFlurry_5.4.0.a'
  s.ios.vendored_library = 'Pods/AppsFlyer-SDK/libAppsFlyerLib.a'

end
```

Comment: Could you check if the lib is build for the needed architectures?  `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info $(FILENAME)`

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: libPods-Shyp.a are: i386 x86_64

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: libFlurry_5.4.0.a are: armv7s i386 x86_64 armv6 armv7 arm64

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: libAppsFlyerLib.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: @René seem to be built for the correct architecture

Answer (score 2):

So the answer to this is that when you add the .a file to your custom pod, you also have to add the .a file to your project after installing your custom pod.

Comment: Frameworks and .a files will be included in 0.36(Next Release) of CocoaPods.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the Podspec?

Comment: Hi after 5 years, can we do it in podspec?